# Django barfs at pickling of the session object when using LDAP authentication backend,

Tags: django, ldap, pickle, django-authentication

I've set up [Django LDAP authentication](http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/)
following [this example](http://www.djm.org.uk/using-django-auth-ldap-active-directory-ldaps/). And it seems that backend actually works, i.e. I have confirmed that

- LDAP access works perfectly via [python-ldap](http://www.python-ldap.org/)
- Debug shows that user can actually authenticate
- User and UserProfile objects are created (and stored to DB with no problems)

However, when the resulting page after the successful logon is being rendered, I get a `PicklingError:  Can't pickle <type 'module'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.module failed`

There are no such problems when using the `model` authentication backend. Also, the variables in the failing call all look just ok. Here is the backtrace:

```
Traceback:
File "<anonymized>/lib/Django-1.4.1-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  188.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "<anonymized>/lib/Django-1.4.1-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py" in process_response
  36.                 request.session.save()
File "<anonymized>/lib/Django-1.4.1-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in save
  52.             session_data=self.encode(self._get_session(no_load=must_create)),
File "<anonymized>/lib/Django-1.4.1-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in encode
  79.         pickled = pickle.dumps(session_dict, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

Exception Type: PicklingError at /
Exception Value: Can't pickle <type 'module'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.module failed
```

The session dict is quite similar as for a user from `model` backend except for the item `'_auth_user_backend': 'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',`

Comment: How is my question off-topic?

Comment: I've got the exact same thing happening.